# invalid class “LogMap” object: Rownames must be supplied When trying to create a Seurat object

Tags: r, dataframe, seurat

I've been trying to create a Seurat object:

```
nuc.seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = as.matrix(UMIs), project = i, min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
```

however I keep on getting the following error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “LogMap” object: Rownames must be supplied
```

The weird thing is, just a day ago it worked completely fine with the exact same pipline.
UMIs in this case is a count dataframe, and it has rownames (despite what the error is suggesting):

```
         Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4
A1BG          21       0       6       1
A1BG-AS1       2       0       0       0
A1CF           9       3       8       2
A2M           17       0       4       0
A2M-AS1        0       0       0       0
```

(UMIs is a lot larger this is just a subset)

I do not have a lot of experience in R or using Seurat so any input would help! Thank you!

I have tried removing some pf the input args of CreateSeuratObject and that did work:

```
nuc.seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = as.matrix(UMIs), project = i, min.cells = 3)
```

However, filtering by min.features at this step reduces object size and eliminates other error down the line (NA data and so on). So it's not a good enough solution.

Comment: If you have recently changed between **Matrix** < 1.6-2 and **Matrix** >= 1.6-2, then you should re-install **SeuratObject** from sources.

Comment: I've tried re-installing SeuratObject and the problem persists. Trying to downgrade Matrix does'nt work either as SeuratObject calls for the newest version for some reason.

Comment: Yes, sorry - my advice applies to **SeuratObject** version 5.0.0, not version 5.0.1.  If you think that there is a regression, then you can consider creating an issue on GitHub: `bug.report(package="SeuratObject")`.